# Jaspersoft Studio: Sort table by calculated value in group footer?

Tags: jasper-reports

We get records of events from a database through JasperReport's domain layer. Each record contains users and time values:

```
userid0 | 00:20:10 | 00:15:00
userid2 | 00:12:00 | 00:17:00
userid0 | 00:05:05 | 00:02:30
userid1 | 00:25:00 | 00:50:00
```

Our table shall list cumulated values for each user. The times per record are simply summed up in a variable. For the example above the result would be:

```
userid0 | 00:25:15 | 00:17:30
userid1 | 00:25:00 | 00:50:00
userid2 | 00:12:00 | 00:17:00
```

In addition the ratio of the resulting two time values shall be displayed (as percent).
The calculation is done by grouping the users, and the results are shown in a group footer (discarding the "details"); so here we would have three group footers:

```
userid0 | 00:25:15 | 00:17:30 | 144%
userid1 | 00:25:00 | 00:50:00 |  50%
userid2 | 00:12:00 | 00:17:00 |  71%
```

How do I sort the table according to the "%" values in the 4th column? The value does not correspond to a data field, and is contained in the group footer only. But the requirement is to sort the whole table by this value, e.g. ascending from 50% to 144%, and additionally restrict the result to the first (or last) 5 rows (i.e. users).

Of course the required result could be achieved by SQL, but as stated above, we are using the domain layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though answering your own question may seem an odd approach I am writing this (at least) for documentation purposes:

After research and trial & error we decided to go without the domain layer in this case, because this seems not to be feasible at all. An elaborate SQL statement will do the trick.

This simplifies the table in that the calculation and grouping is done by the database (thus improving performance), and therefore no more grouping is required in the report's table -- we can use the details section the ordinary way, just showing the results from the query.